What would US socialism look like?
Marxism Leninism adapts itself to it's setting. (It's material conditions.)
In this fanfiction of mine a socialist government is installed in the US by the head of an army.
I'm curious. What would US Marxism Leninism look like?

It's your story, you decide it. This is not really a problem about the rules of your world, which is what worldbuilding is about.

(Full disclosure: I was born, raised and educated in an Eastern European socialist country. We really truely did study the stuff in school, from middle school to university. I did pay attention.) Why on Earth would an American revolutionary government have anything to do with Leninism? Leninism is the brilliant adaptation of Marxist revolutionary thought to the specific conditions of a very large, very poor and underpopulated country, which had not yet gone through a proper bourgeois revolution and had not yet industrialized. The USA is not such a country. Leninism is simply not applicable.

P.S. Leninism is Marxism applied to a very poor, underdeveloped country, where the socialist revolution had to be done before its time, that is, before a proper bourgeois revolution. By contrast, America is a very rich, highly developed country. In such a country other developments of Marxism may be much more applicable, for example libertarian socialism or libertarian Marxism. Lenin died one hundred years ago; things have changed a lot since then.

The act of installing a government onto the US by the head of an army would preclude socialism for quite some time. Much like how the Normans were focused on control after they conquered England, the new government will have most of its energy focused on how to control the land filled with groups constantly trying to overthrow it.

VTC:Opinion-Based. Also a violation of the [help/dont-ask] book rule. Whole textbooks exist about socialism and I have no doubt an entire library could be written describing what a post-capitalism socialist U.S. could (could!) look like - and that library of certainly well-researched books would still only be guessing. Stack Exchange's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. It is, unfortunately, the worst possible place to ask brainstorming questions.

There are realistically 2 options: The first is it would look like every other time Marxism has been tried - the country would be turned to crap, financially ruined, before private business (beholden to the State) was allowed - e.g. China. The second option (which is far more likely) - is that the worlds largest fighting force: 82 Million gun-owning Americans would have something to say about it - and good luck getting the US Military to go along with it without massive defections.

In much of the US political debate, socialism is used to describe any position even slightly to the left of Attila the Hun. So how about some kind of warlord imposing

mandatory health insurance for all employees, taken out of their salary, plus coverage for seniors and the unemployed, covered out of the general tax revenue (taxes would go up ...),
paid maternity leave for all mothers,
sufficient welfare payments to cover minimum shelter, clothing, and food for all who cannot provide for themselves, again covered out of the general taxes,
a maximum working week of 48 hours for all workers (salaried or hourly) and several weeks of paid leave per year, plus rules which required businesses to document compliance,
free schools and universities.

In Europe, that would be considered social-democrat at most. Many conservatives could live with it. But it the US, it would be a radical revolution.

You're not just-a-kiddin'. Out here in Montana that agenda would place a "Don't Tread On Me" flag on every truck, lead to a new form of "Let's Go Brandon" bumper sticker and bring about lengthy editorials in the local rag. I can hear all the rifle bolts cycling in my sleep. Assuming any of what I just said could happen with a warlord in charge. I wonder if the OP understands the difference between socialism and the military-totalitarian culture in Lenin's Russia and post-Lenin U.S.S.R.?

Well, it would be considered social-democrat because it is not a form of socialism. Socialism isn't whatever you want it to be; it has a definition, according to which it is a political-economic system where social ownership of means of production is dominant. If private ownership of means of production is dominant instead, then there is no socialism even if the state is kind and caring, and socialist governments that met this definition were cruel and indifferent just as often as not. These are two separate things whichever way you look at it.

@ihaveideas, socialism has a definiton in Marxist theory. And different ones in the political practice of various cultures. Insisting on the historical definition is helpful if one debates other historians. Less helpful when it comes to contemporary or near-future politics. Language is a social construct, re-negotiated by every new generation.

@o.m. , thank you. Of course; socialism is a utopian system, great in theory but real people just keep messing it up in inventive ways. Changing the definition to match what is achievable in practice is just a roundabout admission of its impossibility. Still, Marx and Lenin had their ideas which they wrote down for everyone to see, and tried to implement them and ended up with something rather different; not much point in claiming long after the fact that they said one thing but really meant something else.

@ihaveideas, socialism is also the self-proclaimed label for more than a dozen European political parties. You can of course declare that they are no true socialists, but then you come dangerously close to the true Scotsman fallacy.

@o.m. , thank you. Oh there absolutely are true socialists: they are the people and parties who hold the belief that social ownership of means of production should be predominant. People and parties who do not hold this belief and call themselves socialists regardless are more accurately described as identifying as socialists. I only follow closely the UK's and Poland's politics, and can confirm that PES's member parties from these two countries do not hold that belief and are therefore not socialist. Nor do they identify as such; they call themselves 'social-democratic', and accurately so.

It was never mainstream, and McCarthyism drove it deeply underground, but from about the 1850s up until the 1950s, the United States did have a relatively large trend of militant socialism and socialist-adjacent movements among factory workers, railroad workers, and miners. Some of these movements were Soviet inspired Marxist-Leninists, but there were also a lot of syndicalists and anarcho-communists, which are strains that seemed to have more popularity in America. A number of these groups still technically exist, though much smaller and in different forms. While obviously the conditions of the US in the 2020s are different than they were in the 1920s, I'd still say its more likely a US socialist movement would resemble prior US socialist movements than it necessarily would Marxist-Leninism.
I would look into Eugene V. Debs, Mother Jones (the person, not the later magazine), Emma Goldman, Emil Seidel, the International Workers of the World, the Socialist Labor Party of America, the Haymarket Affair, the Battle of Blair Mountain, the West Virginia Coal Wars, the Colorado Labor Wars, and other late 19th and early 20th century socialists for a look at how American socialism has trended in the past.
A lot of it was organized by and revolved around trade unions with the end goal of having the workers directly take over their workplace, with decision making about how to run the factory voted on democratically and with all the profits made distributed equally to the workers doing the work, rather than with most going to company owners and shareholders. It was much more bottom up than top down than Soviet Marxist Leninism, and there wasn't really a focus on creating a national government; instead hey had a vision of a federations of various trade unions from different industries that would all collaborate to provide services, with no one person or group being directly in charge.
Labor strikes were the main tactic, but also sabotaging machinery, harassing, kidnapping, and assassinating executives, and obviously getting more places to unionize.
The focus on unions and lack of direct hierarchy did mean however that there was often a lot of infighting and factionalism that company management could exploit to break strikes, and that as union membership declined into the modern day, these movements became too weak to mount significant challenge.
A modern American equivalent would likely be similar in goal and tactics, being union based, but rather than being focused around unionizing industries like steel mills and coal mines, would now occur in industries more relevant to the modern day American like technology, IT, retail, restaurants, etc.
Also worth noting is that American socialist movements were always directly opposed by the military. While there have been historically a number of individual US military figures who were socialists or were friendly towards them the US military as an institution is very unlikely to impose socialism or by sympathetic to a socialist movement.

This is almost an answer. You've directed the OP to research, but brought none of that research into your answer, thus failing to answer the OP's question. Can you bring examples of what the 1920s-era socialists advocated into your answer and explain how that would look and/or work in 2024 America? It's going to be a bit of work (the broad nature of the question is one of the reasons I voted to close), but that's what it'll take to be an answer to the question.

My apologies, I have gone back and added more detail. Still, this is a topic that hundreds of books have been written on, and the people themselves wrote hundreds more, so I'd still consider this just a jumping off point.

Thanks for the improvement. Keep in mind for future reference that the [help/dont-ask]'s Book Rule states, "... questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." It's a reason to close questions on a service that wants specific and focused questions. Cheers.

We don't have to guess: a Socialist Party USA already exists. Its Principles aren't that far off from the Leninist ones. The only major difference is that SPUSA is not a revolutionary party: it seeks to be elected into power, instead of taking it by force.
...and therein lies the problem. "The head of an army imposing socialism" is mutually exclusive with SPUSA's goal of being elected. Much (most?) of the military may remain loyal to the previous government, resulting in a civil war, in which case SPUSA's peaceful means will not allow the socialist government to stay in power. So assuming that it does want to stay in power, you would end up with something more similar to war communism, into which Leninism promptly evolved in order to cope with the Russian Civil War, and possibly also the Red Terror if the socialist government's position becomes sufficiently weak. (Although to be honest, the democratic loyalists may well become just as rigid and bloodthirsty when threatened with military defeat.) About 10% of Russian Empire's population died in the process of enacting Leninism; for the present day USA, this corresponds to over 30 million deaths. All I can say is: not recommended.

This isn't an answer to the OP's question. It could have been a Frame Challenge had it answered the OP's question in the context of the alternatives mentioned, but as it did not, it's merely a lengthy comment to the question.
